# How to load assets from a framework on iOS 16?

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

I have a private library which contains image assets for many of my apps. I include this library using CocoaPods in my app, using a local path and `use_frameworks!`.

I use the following code for opening an image from the bundle included in the library:

```
NSBundle *podBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self classForCoder]];
NSBundle *imagesBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[podBundle URLForResource:@"LibKwindoo" withExtension:@"bundle"]];
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ImageName"] inBundle:imagesBundle compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
```

This worked fine until iOS 16, and works still fine under iOS 15 when I compile using iOS 16 SDK, but on iOS 16, the image gets just `nil`. The bundles seem to be correct. I also checked and the files are present in the compiled `.car` asset bundle which is included in the `.app`.

UPDATE: Even stranger: I experience this only when running the app from Xcode on the device or in the Simulator. When I run the same app independently on the device, it works!

What changed on iOS 16 which prevents me to load images from this asset bundle?

Comment: also experiencing the same thing